# Can I submit to a high school journal and "real" journal at the same time?

Tags: paper-submission, etiquette, social-science

I'm a high school student that did some research in Social Science. My research is novel enough that I think that I have a chance of getting published in a "real" journal with an impact factor (although my chances are very low). I also want to submit to some high school journals, where I think I have a much higher chance of getting published.

I know that you are not supposed to submit your research to more than one journal at a time, but since high school journals aren't really in the same category as the "real" journals, is it okay to submit to both at the same time in this case? I know that you're allowed to submit to a preprint website like arXiv at the same time, so why would this be different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is that you don't do this. If the "high school" journal accepts the paper then the other journal will have an issue, wasting time with your paper. Choose one, perhaps the standard journal and submit there. If your paper really has value then it will take a while, but might be accepted. If they think the quality isn't up to their standards then the rejection is likely to be fairly quick and you can then submit to the other.

ArXiv is intended for preprints, not alternate publication. And not all journals will accept a paper that has already appeared in arXiv. A journal aimed at secondary students isn't a preprint journal. ArXiv doesn't use a standard review process in any case, just "junk filtering" process.

And, only one high school journal at a time. It is, in part, a matter of respect for the effort they put in for the review process.